# C++ simple array element comparison

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay I don't know if this is even a valid question but I'm posting here because I don't know where else to turn with this. I just started studying programming this half year at a university and we just had the final exam, which  I failed. Basically, there were 4 questions, and while the second one looked easy it was actually tricky and I just can't figure out how it should have been done.

Basically the problem is: There is a bank, and when people log in to do business, you need to write a program that records the time they logged in (0-24h), the minutes (0-59), the type of transaction they choose (1 for logging in with a bank card, -1 for logging out with the same bank card, 2 for money input into the account, -2 for withdrawal) and finally either their bank acc number (if they pressed 1 or -1 previously), or the amount they are withdrawing or putting in (if they chose 2 or -2).

Basically here is how we had to do it:

```
int n; //size of the array or number of ppl who transacted that day
cin >> n;
int bank[n][4];
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
  cin >> bank[n][0];
  cin >> bank[n][1];
  cin >> bank[n][2];
  cin >> bank[n][3];
}
```

This fills up all the info and then,

basically a sample input looked like this for 4 customers during the day:

1. 11 40 1 458965
2. 12 20 2 6000
3. 15 40 -1 458965
4. 16 25 -2 18000

Here is the part I could not solve:

Our test asked us: **How many people were logged in from 12 o clock to 13:00 oclock?**

At first I did

```
int count=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
  if (bank[i][0]==12)
{
  count=count+1;
}
}

cout << count;
```

The problem with this, is that it does not account for people who log in before 12 with a 1 in the third column, but log out at later than 1 oclock with a -1. Which means they were still logged in from 12 to 1pm.

so then I did

```
int count=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
  if (bank[i][0]==12)
  {
    count=count+1;
  }
  if (bank[i][2]==-1)
  {
    count=count+1;
  }
}

cout << count;
```

but then I realized that this would count some logins twice, because if they logged in at 12 with a 1 for example, then logged out at 3 o clock with a -1 it would count that one person twice.

It also asked us **what is the longest period that any person was logged in, assuming the bank kicks everyone off at 24:00**. I honestly am not even sure how to even begin that one.

EDIT: SORRY i edited a bunch of stuff to make it clearer and correct code. I'm not too good at this yet forgive my mistakes

Comment: The sample input you have showed is not clear to me. 1. Is it the data for 1 user or 4 users? 2a. If it is for 1 user, how come there's a -2 after -1 (meaning they withdrew from the account after logging out)? 2b. If it is for 4 users, the information is incomplete.

Comment: Btw: for (i=0; i ; ++i) would never excecute.

Comment: Please add commands or use a enum for the commands. bank[i][0] vs bank[i][withdraw]. You also could replace the i with a better name: bank[customer][withdraw]. You also could add abstraction. That would make everything even simpler. It's almost impossible to see what happens in your code without scrolling up and down all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I didn’t know how the bank system works. So I made a minimal example for you. 
I also didn't know if you used classes before, so I wrote it without.

I cleaned your code a bit:

```
//Use these enums
enum action { action_login = 1, action_logout = -1, action_input = 2, action_output = -2 };
enum information {information_time_h, information_time_m, information_action, information_bankNumber};

//Place this in the function you have
int peapelToInput = 0; //size of the array or number of ppl who transacted that day
cin >> peapelToInput;

for (int i=0; i<peapelToInput; ++i)
{
    //Maby add error handeling? When some one inputs a 'a', it won't do what you want. 
    cin bank[i][information_time_h];
    cin bank[i][information_time_m];
    cin bank[i][information_action];
    cin bank[i][information_bankNumber];
}
```

As you can see, I made the code cleaner by adding enums. This makes developing a lot easier.

The login code:

```
int count=0;
int bankSize = bank.size(); //I guess it's a vector?
for (int i=0; i < bankSize; ++i)
{
    if (bank[i][information_time_h] == 12 && bank[i][information_action] == action_login)
        count++;
}
cout << "logins at 12:00 - 12:59:" << count << endl;
```

You can do 2 checks in 1 if, I increment count when they were logedin from 12:00 - 12:59. Do you need exclude people that were loggedout?

The longest time code:

```
//A function to search when he is logedout
int findLogoutIndex(int start, int accountNumber, XXX bank)
{
    int bankSize = bank.size();
    for (int i=start; i < bankSize; ++i)
        if( bank[i][information_action] == action_logout && bank[i][information_bankNumber] == accountNumber)
            return i;

    return -1; //Handle this error
}

//And how it workes
int logenst = 0;
int indexLongest = 0;
int bankSize = bank.size(); //I guess it's a vector?
for (int i=0; i < bankSize; ++i)
{
    if( bank[i][information_action] != action_login )
        continue;

    int logoutIndex = findLogoutIndex(i,bank[i][information_bankNumber],bank);
    //check if logoutIndex is not -1, or handle the error on an other way.

    int loginTimeHour = bank[logoutIndex][information_time_h] - bank[i][information_time_h];
    int loginTimeMinute = bank[logoutIndex][information_time_m] - bank[i][information_time_m];   
    int loginTime = (loginTimeHour * 100) + loginTimeMinute;

    if( logenst < loginTime)
    {
        logenst = loginTime;
        indexLongest = i;
    }
}
cout << "longest is: H:" << bank[indexLongest][information_time_h] << " M: " << bank[indexLongest][information_time_m] << endl;
```

You don't need to keep the time format, this way makes comparing a lot easier. Just save the longest login time and the index number of it. That way you can easily access all the data you want.

I didn't take the time to write "good code". But you asked how it can be done, I guess this is good enough to understand it?

I didn't test the code and wrote it in Notepad. So I don't know if it will compile.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used enumerators yet but I'll learn them now. and I'll test this code and try to make it work in case it doesn't. thanks for your help.

Comment: Oops, the longest login time isn't correct. You need to search when he is logedout and substract that from the login time.

Comment: I fixed the code. My variable names are not very logic, if I where you I would rename them if you want to work further on this code.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to know is what the questions are actually asking. In the first case, *How many people were logged in from 12 o clock to 1 oclock?* can mean multiple things. It could mean how many people were logged in during the whole period or how many people were logged in at any given time between those two hours. The difference is whether someone that logs in at 12:15 and logs out at 12:30 is counted or not. The second question is calculating the longest period someone was logged in, and that can be done at the same time.

One possible approach would be managing a lookup table from user id to login times. You read the input linearly, whenever someone logs in you add an entry `(acct, time)` into the table. When they log out you lookup the account number and calculate the difference of times. If the difference is greater than the maximum you store the new maximum.

For the first question, at 12 you can create a set of the people that was logged in from that lookup table. Whenever someone logs out between that time and 1 you find whether the person was in the set and you remove it if so. When you find the first operation after 1, the set contains the account numbers of all the people that was logged in for the whole period from 12 to 1.

If the question was getting all people that was logged at *any* time in the period, instead of removing from the set those users that log out before 1, you need to include new users that log in inside the period. At the end of the period the set contains all users that were logged in at any time within the period.

You only need to perform a single pass over the input data which means that you don't even need to store all of the transactions in memory, only the map/set required above. The overall cost of the operation is `O(n log n)` on the number of operations. (Disclaimer: I haven't done the math, this is a hunch :))

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this. Nevertheless, the process followed should be correct.

I'm sure this can still be optimized in terms of execution speed.

Also, I assume by time 12 you mean 12:00 and by time 1 you mean 13:00.

```
int main()
{
    int answer = 0;
    //  For each transaction
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {

        //  If logged in before 12:00
        //  bank[i][2] > 0 tells you user logged in.
        if ( bank[i][0] < 12 && bank[i][2] > 0 ) {
            //  Loop through each following transaction.
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < count; j++ ) {
                //  If logged out after 13:00
                if ( bank[j][0] > 13 && bank[j][2] < 0 ) {
                    //  Now to check if it was the same user who logged in earlier - how?:
                    //  Only way to differentiate is by comparing the transaction amounts and types.
                    if ( (bank[i][3] == bank[j][3]) && (bank[i][2] == -1*bank[j][2]) ) {    //  log-in code = -1 * log-out code.
                       answer++;    //  Number of transactions that spanned from before 12:00 till after 13:00.
                    //  Remember, a single person can't have multiple log-ins at the same time. ( assumption )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually very similar to what I wanted to try (in theory) near the very end of the test when we had 5 minutes left, except mine never worked and I couldn't even finish it properly. I'm going to try this now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, hope it works. I've been in that 'last 5 minutes' situation many a time haha! Just noticed you edited your question - to find the longest logged time would also follow a similar method to the first question ( with the time limits changed from (12;13) to (0;24) ). Then you would need to save the first transactions time and replace it if the next transactions time is longer. If you can't find the corresponding log-out transaction for any user, you know they didn't log out - then you can use 24 as their log-out time for the logged time duration calculation.

Comment: Dude! Your code worked (with a bit of modifying)! And as I'm reading your comment I think I now know how to do the last question too. Why the hell didn't I think of this on the test? Now I better be able to do  the retake or I'll need to retake the entire stupid course. Thanks again man.